# System Error &H8000FFF (-247418113). Catastrophic failure

Tags: excel, vba, crash

I have now twice had this error, where I email a spreadsheet with macros to another person.  It is working when I send it using share via email.  When they get it there is a problem.  When I go and open the original, I also get the problem.  **System Error &H8000FFF (-247418113). Catastrophic failure** and when I go to look at the code it is all gone.  Does anyone know the cause and solution?

One strange this that happened, I would get an error when clicking on the Data tab, something to do with Funcres.  When I when I looked online, it said this was an add-in.  Since I wasn't using it, I disabled it.  Not sure if that is related.

Comment: Sending vba/macros through email can be tricky as they are usually blocked because they are a common cause of malware infections. Unless there is specific vba code you want us to look at this isn't really a programming question.

Comment: This likely has nothing to do with VBA. I would try repairing office and/or reinstalling it. It sounds like Excel and/or some of the addins might be corrupted.

Comment: It's time to accept the answer below. I only started to encounter this problem recently (since OneDrive sync introduced, Excel dog slow and this error from time to time). Solution for self and colleagues is always New Module, move code per @Jamie answer below.

Comment: It was a while ago, but I remember this happening and I think I found it had to do with having a blank module.  I recorded an operation to see what the code would look like and then deleted the code without deleting the module.  Everything worked fine and then I would send it to a client and it would not work.  I would reopen the file and have the same issue as the client.

Answer (score 6):

I got this error simply by opening the spreadsheet in the morning after it was working just fine the night before. Rebooting and reloading did not help.
I managed to fix this by creating a new module in VBA, copying across the code that was failing into the new module and then deleting the original module.

Comment: Commenting for visibility - same thing happened to me (nothing with forms or images as I've found in other forums) - creating a new module and copying the code over worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

So I figured it out.  The issue was I had left a black module in the VBA editor.  I had recosted a macro to get a code for a color and then deleted the macro but did not delete the module2.

I did this on two different spreadsheets for two different people.  They were working when I sent them but crashed for them.  When they sent them back they crashed for me.

The one thing they had in common was this empty module2.  I entered each with macros disabled, deleted the module2's and enable macros and both are now working fine and have been for weeks.